# How to keep same position of recyclerview's progressbar?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-listview, android-viewholder

Here I have a viewHolderclass of recyclerview, in which I implement OnClickListener button like below code.

```
public class RemoveHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
{
 Button removeButton;
 private RemoveHolder (@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            removeButton =itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove_button);
            removeProgress =itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove_progress);
            removeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.remove_button)
            {
                    buttonToProgressAnim();
                    List.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
}
```

exactly what I get:

1. after removing item by clicking button, progressbar appear.
2. progressbar is still appear of removed position

[clicked position 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2dbo.jpg)

[progressbar at 0 at new position and its appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRGsj.jpg)

[same thing happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFis1.jpg)

Now exactly what I want:

1. after removing item by clicking button, progressbar will also gone with recycler item and it will not affect at other position

Comment: try this `notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition())`

Comment: Also tried notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition())